# I'm not able to install opencv in pycharm?

Tags: pycharm, opencv, python

I have downloaded opencv through cmd using `pip install opencv-python`. But when I run simple read write program in pycharm it couldn't load `import cv2` command when I search then, I came to know that pycharm have some other way to install opencv. I did it `setting->project->project interperter` then I search for
***opencv-python*** but it gives me this error during installation:

```
Collecting opencv-python
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/opencv-python/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/opencv-python/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping

pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/opencv-python/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/opencv-python/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/opencv-python/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/opencv-python/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/opencv-python/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-python (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for opencv-python
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
```

I have the latest version of python and pip but though I am getting this error could anyone help me, please.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely that you installed opencv in the base conda environment and not the environment you activated as interpreter or that you installed it in the environment you created and have the base env activated:

Try the following set of steps:

`conda create -n envname python`

`conda activate envname`

`pip install opencv-python`

Go to pycharm and add the envname environment to pycharm interpreters, activate it and then run the code.

Comment: how can i add envname to pycharm intertpreters?

Comment: Go to File -> Settings -> Project interpreter -> then from the drop down list press show all -> then press '+' -> then check 'existing environment' -> then click on the '...' near Interpreter list -> then go to path c/users/your_user/anaconda3/envs/envname/python.exe, then press ok and run the project

Answer (score 0):

Your initial error is:

```
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))
```

If you are Windows user, set following paths to System's **PATH** environment variable:

If using Anaconda:

```
<system_path>\Anaconda3
<system_path>\Anaconda3\scripts
<system_path>\Anaconda3\Library\bin
```

If only Python is installed on your system then(I am assuming Python 3.6 is installed in your system):

```
<system_path_where_python_is_installed>\Python36
<system_path_where_python_is_installed>\Python36\Scripts
<system_path_where_python_is_installed>\Python36\Library\bin
```

And then try to install opencv via PyCharm.

Hope this solves your problem.